# How to make AWS REST API return a JSON instead of XML

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

In AWS I invoke the call ListQueues on sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com (by calling directly to the REST API)

The response is always an XML, and searching in the AWS documentation I couldn't find how to get a JSON.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not convert the XML to JSON in your app (either by traversing it for the stuff you want or with some third-party plugin)?

Comment: I don't wish to convert. I wish to get a JSON results directly

Comment: if you are using lambda with api-gateway...simply send json from lambda response

Comment: This is not the same as api-gateway. I'm calling to AWS own management API. The same way your command line tool does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Provide the `Accept: application/json` header and you'll get a JSON response.

Edit: AWS doesn't have much (any?) documentation on the return types.
I made a pip module that documents some of the return types that may
be helpful as a reference: https://pypi.org/project/awsxmltojson/

Comment: Did you try it?  or it is a guess ?

Comment: It works. Here's the response from an empty queue with a GET call to `<queue url>?Action=ReceiveMessage`:

`{"ReceiveMessageResponse":{"ReceiveMessageResult":{"messages":null},"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"9e23d5c5-1f81-5868-bade-8d437a2231e8"}}}`

Comment: This is not about a *specific* queue call. It is about the ListQueues API call.

Comment: Here's a response for `https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListQueues`: ```{
"ListQueuesResponse": {
"ListQueuesResult": {
"NextExclusiveStartQueueName": null,
"NextToken": null,
"queueUrls": []
},
"ResponseMetadata": {
"RequestId": "a7f38b75-cb64-5ef7-b202-d3fd30eeb26c"
}
}
}```

Comment: Thank you, I also needed this. I already had JSON bindings in my software, so I prefer parsing JSON over XML. Works perfectly.

Comment: Hm.. Using the `Accept: application/json` header for the `ListObjects(v2)` REST API still returns XML.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible to get JSON response from SQS available actions. Response will always be XML data structures.

> In response to an action request, Amazon SQS returns an XML data
>   structure that contains the results of the request.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-responses.html

Comment: Very sad indeed